# Mask a directory folder name with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this URL: https://example.com/sub/product and I don't want to show "sub" in my URL so that the final URL would look like https://example.com/product and would redirect the indexed URLs to this URL. Is it possible? Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-0-9]+)$ index.php?goto=$1 [L,NC]
ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)$  index.php?goto=$1&catidx=$2     [L,NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /404/404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on

#--redirect from "/sub/foo to "/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sub/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
#--rewrite "/foo" to its orignal location "/sub/foo"
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /sub/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but its not working for me.When i add this code my css files are broken in some pages and in some pages gives 500..I think i cannot right with the old codes..Any ideas ?